# How to create a dynamic main menu tabs

Tags: routes

I want to create a dynamic main menu according to user roles. For example if an anonymous user visits he can only see the 'Home' and 'About Us' links, while registered users can see additional links like 'Contact Us'. Is there a way to do that, through a module perhaps? I don't want to edit in source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Menu per Role](https://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role) module.

Project page says:

> This module allows you to restrict access to menu items based on user
>   roles. It depends on the Drupal core menu.module just activate both
>   modules and edit a menu item as usual. There will be a new fieldset
>   that allows you to restrict access by role. The fieldset also appears
>   in the node edit form.

Comment: It tells me that this module is incompatible with drupal 7.x, is there an equivalent or Should I download the development release?

Comment: You can use its development release.